# Weird accuracy in multilabel classification keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, sparse-matrix, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel classification problem, I used the following code but the validation accuracy jumps to 99% in the first epoch which is weird given the complexity of the data as the input features are 2048  extracted from inception model (pool3:0) layer and the labels are [1000],(here is the link of a file contains samples of features and label : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxI_8PO3YBPPYkp6dHlGeExpS1k/view?usp=sharing ),
 is there something I am doing wrong here ??

Note: labels are  sparse vector contain only 1 ~ 10 entry as 1 the rest is zeros

```python
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The output of prediction is zeros !

What wrong I do in training the model to bother the prediction ?

```python
#input is the features file and labels file

def generate_arrays_from_file(path ,batch_size=100):
x=np.empty([batch_size,2048])
y=np.empty([batch_size,1000])
while True:
    f = open(path)
    i = 1  
    for line in f:
        # create Numpy arrays of input data
        # and labels, from each line in the file
        words=line.split(',')
        words=map(float, words[1:])
        x_= np.array(words[0:2048])
        y_=words[2048:]
        y_= np.array(map(int,y_))
        x_=x_.reshape((1, -1))
        #print np.squeeze(x_)
        y_=y_.reshape((1,-1))
        x[i]= x_
        y[i]=y_
        i += 1
        if i == batch_size:
            i=1
            yield (x, y)

    f.close()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=2048, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=2048))
model.add(Dense(units=1000, activation="sigmoid", 
kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=
['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_file('train.txt'),
                validation_data= generate_arrays_from_file('test.txt'),
                validation_steps=1000,epochs=100,steps_per_epoch=1000, 
                  verbose=1)
```

Comment: Is the generator creating the labels properly? It sounds like the true values you're giving to the model are all zeros.

Comment: Which are your dataset statistics? If your training dataset is too small you're definitely in an overfitting scenario. If it is not the case, you should try to apply some dropout in order to avoid overfitting.

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia our dataset is 200k images so it's not small , concerning dropout I try it but I have the same problem

Comment: @Daniel I think the problem is from the generators , but I,m sure that the input labels are not all zeros, I generate from files like this way

Comment: Are the classes for a given example independent? Maybe the binary cross entropy it is not the most suitable solution to your problem.

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia I think yeah the classes are independent ,here is the link https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B7EVK8r0v71pWWxJeGVqMjRkUVE  of 1000 classes that describ the style , painting and texture of clothes

Comment: Ok. Seems that you have a single class per example. Have you checked your data as suggested before?

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia it's not a single class , each label from the 1000 labels has a type 1,2,3,4 or 5 , for example 1 corresponding to style of cloth , 2 corresponding to the texture ..etc , each image in our dataset has 1000 labels (with ones corresponding to the labels it has) as for example an image can have these labels :abstract, abstract chevron, abstract chevron print

Comment: What I mean is: a single example does not have multiple labels attached to it. Isn't it?

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia a single example has multiple labels , as each image has multiple labels and i try to predict the labels of other images not in the dataset  using my trained model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem with the accuracy is that your output are sparse.

Keras computes accuracy using this formula:

```
K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

So, in your case, having only 1~10 non zero labels, a prediction of all 0 will yield an accuracy of 99.9% ~ 99%.

As far as the problem not learning, I think the problem is that you are using a sigmoid as last activation and using 0 or 1 as output value. This is bad practice since, in order for the sigmoid to return 0 or 1 the values it gets as input must be very large or very small, which reflects on the net having very large (in absolute value) weights. Furthermore, since in each training output there are far less 1 than 0 the network will soon get to a stationary point in which it simply outputs all zeros (the loss in this case is not very large either, should be around 0.016~0.16).

What you can do is scale your output labels so that they are between (0.2, 0.8) for example so that the weights of the net won't become too big or too small. Alternatively you can use a `relu` as activation function.

Comment: thank u but I still have the same problem , I scaled the output from 0.2 to 0.8 but my model doesn't predict correctly as the outputs also resides at 0,2

Comment: Try using the `relu`. Alternatively, have you tried adding some more hidden layers? Going deeper is usually better than going wider. It looks like you are trying to model a complex problem with a very shallow network. 1000 labels are a lot, [GoogLeNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842.pdf) uses a very deep net to classify images using the same number of labels (although they have224x224 images as inputs). What you could do is try to classify using less labels and then increase the number (start with 10 then 100 and so on). If it still doeasn't train then there might be a problem with the code

Comment: @gionni what to do if the same problem arises for deep networks as well?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on the data and architecture

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the cosine similarity as loss function?

I had the same multi-label + high dimensionality problem.

The cosine distance takes account of the orientation of the model output (prediction) and the desired output (true class) vector.

It is the normalized dot-product between two vectors.

In keras the cosine_proximity function is -1*cosine_distance. Meaning that -1 corresponds to two vectors with the same size and orientation.